# SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to make a database in android but I have this problem,erase the database file in the (AVD), rename the database in the class "phone", but nothing works!

`02-11 13:00:27.491: E/Database(487): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Phones_Table has no column named nam: , while compiling: INSERT INTO Phones_Table(nam, tel) VALUES(?, ?);`

this is my code:

```
public class Phones {
    public static final String ID_ROW = "_id";
public static final String ID_PERSON = "nam";
public static final String ID_PHONE = "tel";

private static final String N_DB = "Phones";
private static final String N_TABLE = "Phones_Table";
private static final int VERSION_DB = 1;

private DBHelper nHelper;
private final Context nContext;
private SQLiteDatabase nDB;



private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, N_DB, null, VERSION_DB);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + N_TABLE + "(" + 
        ID_ROW + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
        ID_PERSON + "TEXT NOT NULL, "+
        ID_PHONE + "TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + N_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);           
    }

}

public Phones (Context c){

    nContext = c;
}

public Phones open() throws SQLException{
    nHelper = new DBHelper(nContext);
    nDB = nHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    nHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String nam, String tel) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //insert data
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    //put content of name
    cv.put(ID_PERSON, nam);
    //put content of Phone 
    cv.put(ID_PHONE, tel);

    //return content in table
    return nDB.insert(N_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public String receive() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ID_ROW, ID_PERSON, ID_PHONE};
    Cursor c = nDB.query(N_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(ID_ROW);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(ID_PERSON);
    int iPhone = c.getColumnIndex(ID_PHONE);
    //loop
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iPhone) + "\n ";

    }

    return result;
}}
```

really would appreciate your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ID_PERSON + "TEXT NOT NULL, "+
             ^
```

You're missing a space at the indicated position in the `create table` string. Same thing for the next line.

Your table will have columns named `namTEXT` and `telTEXT` without that extra space.

Comment: thank you very much Mat, I fix it, do not understand how I did not see!!